# Does MacOS Support a Snapshot-Style Filesystem?

Tags: backup, macos, filesystem, fusion-drive

I would like to perform daily snapshots that I can revert to if someone:

- downloads Malware
- installs buggy software
- etc.

Does such a thing exist?  Is there a roadmap for it?

I have a Fusion drive so that would affect my personal situation but I am just asking the general question.

Comment: Does Time Machine not do what you want to do?

Comment: Not really.  A snapshot would be instant.  Time Machine would require a restore.  

Can you restore to an image (i.e. an identical copy) as of a certain time using Time Machine?

Comment: IIRC, [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) supports snapshots, but I don't know much about it.  It's still "experimental" though.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's new file system, [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System), supports snapshots.  Per their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Features/Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016999-CH5-DontLinkElementID_17):

[image]

APFS is available in 10.12.x (Sierra) as a Developer Preview and as a [released product in 10.13.x (High Sierra)](https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/05/apple-announces-macos-high-sierra/).

Earlier than Sierra, if you need to make a "point in time" backup, it's best to run Time Machine to ensure a good backup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have Sierra but, reading the documentation, it's only available as a Developer Preview.  That means a [couple of things](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html): 1. You can't put it on your boot drive; and 2. You can't put it on a Fusion drive.

Comment: APFS can not be used on a startup volume though. (Yet?)

Comment: @StephenRasku: Look for announcements about APFS at WWDC next week. My guess is that in 10.13 it'll be usable as a startup volume, but will probably not support Fusion Drive. Fusion Drive is built on top of Core Storage, and APFS doesn't use that. Also, Fusion Drive is really a stopgap for the period when SSDs aren't big enough to be the sole storage device, and need to be paired with a big HD; APFS is really intended for the pure-SSD future. P.S. I reserve the right to delete this comment on Monday, when it turns out I'm completely wrong.

Comment: When I last checked, APFS was still a _developer preview_ technology – **not production quality** – in pre-release macOS 10.13.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't wait for APFS, you could look into [OpenZFS](https://openzfsonosx.org), an implementation of Sun/Oracle's [ZFS filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS). It seems like you can make it work on a macOS boot drive (don't know about Fusion drives), though it's certainly [not trivial](https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/ZFS_on_Boot).