# What is the weird code on my terminal?

Tags: terminal, catalina, malware

Hi I following my previous [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406636/how-to-manually-detect-infections-on-mac), I realised the terminal is showing "Last login:...on ttys000" and sometimes it's showing "Last login:... on console"
May I ask if it is normal or is it a sign that something isn't right?
I tried creating a new user and open the Terminal and it's still showing the same "Last login:...on ttys000"
Can anyone advice?
Thank you so much!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just shows the last time you've logged in/started a Terminal session, there is nothing weird about it.

Comment: In addition, any new Terminal window opened will increment the ttys count by one i.e. ttys000, ttys001, ttys002, etc.